# Can one Laravel route use either session or token authentication?

Tags: api, authentication, laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization

I'm defining my API routes in Laravel 5.4. Most of these routes require authentication, and I would like to be able to  do this auth using either:

- token authentication i.e. `auth:api` (used by other web apps on different domains)
- or using session/cookie auth i.e. `auth`, for AJAX requests in the primary web app

Is it possible to do this, or do I have to define all my routes twice, with a different route group prefix or something? eg Do I have to have all *session auth* API endpoints look like `/ajax/api-endpoint` and all *token auth* API endpoints look like `/api/api-endpoint`?

That feels clumsy and arbitrary — I want to access `/api/api-endpoint` regardless of the auth method I am using.

Specifying both `auth` and `auth:api` middlewares as follows appears to make Laravel require BOTH methods of auth before succeeding, instead of just requiring either one:

`Route::get('api/user', 'MyUserController@index')->middleware(['auth', 'auth:api']);`

Comment: Did you try routes/api.php?

Comment: Yeah, although the routes defined in `api.php` have /api prefixed to their URL automatically, so I have had to put the /ajax/* routes in `web.php` —  which is in fact another displeasing situation in itself lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define this route `Route::get('ajax/user', 'MyUserController@index')` in `web.php`
and `Route::get('api/user', 'MyUserController@index')` in `api.php` so the exact same method of controller can be used in both routes, and in your controller method use `auth()` to obtain the current user no matter if authentication is performed using `auth:api` or only auth `auth()` will give you the user that is authenticated by either one method.

assuming you have group in `web.php` and `api.php` with appropriate middleware applied to group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Essentially you're saying there's no way to avoid inventing an arbitrary second URL just so I can use two auth methods?

Comment: i think you can define your own middleware and in that middleware check your self auth either by web driver or by api driver and if you find user set the user for that request and call next in the middleware that way you can end up with single route and a wrapper middleware around raw auth

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense — much easier just to have two URLs so I think I'll do that :)